# Migrate 2 mysql folders on same server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, xampp

I have installed wamp initailly. But now we have moved to xamp. So, I have 2 mysql folders,

```
C:\xampp\mysql
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql\data
```

Now my localhost is pointing to `C:\xampp\mysql`. I just wanna move everything from `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql` to `C:\xampp\mysql`. When I move it I get some errors.

I just need to import one database with the same permisions

Comment: No, transfer between `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql` and `\xampp\mysql`

Comment: what do you mean Rick? Sorry I ddidnt get

Comment: You mean should I replace complete mysql folders? Actually I upgraded mySQL and I wanna to run my databases in this new version of mySQL

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%';`  If the directories were the same, you should be able to simply upgrade MySQL without moving anything around.  (But be sure to run `mysql_upgrade`.)

Comment: The dirs are pointing to `C:\xampp` and others are pointing to `C:\wamp\..`